# Best way to access ext partion in windows?

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, ext3

What is the most stable and easiest way to get readable access of linux partitions in windows?

All software and drivers I´ve found seem to have been dead/inactive for at least 4 years.

Native access is a plus.

Os: Windows 8.1

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of options, such as:

- **UPDATE 2022/July**: You can also [mount using WSL v2+](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk) (Apologies for the link only but the instructions are rather long). This is almost certainly the best method in 2022.
- Create a Linux VM using VirtualBox or similar. This is rather heavy really but works as you can share the drives
- [Ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) - Updated Nov 2017 for Ext3 (Ext4 work in progress). It is free
- [DiskInternals Linux Reader](http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) - Not sure when this was last update but still seems current
- [Ext2read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/) - seems pretty dead but still works OK I think. You need to run this as an admin user
- [Explore2fs](http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs) - Not updated for a while and doesn't mention Windows 7 or 8 but I believe it does work at least on W7
- [Paragon ExtFS](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-windows/) - is still current and works on W8 too. Supports read and write and is free for personal use.